# Powershell Command to copy from network location to all users profile

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

I'd like a simple command to copy a shortcut for `Devices and Printer.lnk` to All Users Profile Start Menu so that I can pin this shortcut to every users start menu that logs in to the Windows 10 PC at logon.

I've exported my start menu but having read up on it doesn't seem possible to pin the Devices and Printers shortcut in the normal fashion. This is why I've uploaded the shortcut to a network location that all users have access to, if I can copy this to a location on the PC that all users have access to then I can adjust my startmenu script so that it appears as a tile.

I can copy the shortcut to a basic location (the logged on user) but not to all users folder?

I thought that the following would work but doesn't:

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\Server\Share\*.lnk" -Destination "$env:allusersprofile\APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
```

Appreciate your help.

---

**Edit**: I have resolved the above issue however, it's lead me on to a follow on issue. I apply this script when a user logs in to Windows 10 but I then want to run a separate task (that is a part of the same ps1 file) which removes a whole host of Bloatware from the OS.

I've tried to add a `;` and additionally and but they both still require the user to login twice to complete both tasks. My full script at the moment is:

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\Server\Share\*.lnk" -Destination "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"; $AppList = @( "*Microsoft.3dbuilder*" etc etc*" ) foreach ($App in $AppList) { Get-AppxPackage -Name $App | Remove-AppxPackage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```

I've added "etc etc" as there's a load of commands below that I won't include that remove the bloatware.

Comment: @Theo OK, sorry. Think I'm there now

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Remove-AppxPackage` does not have a `-NoRestart` switch. However, you can try if a restart can be avoided by restarting the File Explorer after you have done the copying and removing with this: `Stop-Process -ProcessName Explorer`. Stopping File Explorer in PowerShell should restart the shell automatically.

Comment: I'd use [group-policy-preferences](https://www.blackforce.co.uk/2015/05/06/create-desktop-start-menu-shortcuts-using-) to create the shortcut. Much easier to maintain than a logon script!

Comment: Hi @JamesC. I have it working now however, I can't get two Powershell commands to run one after the other. It results in me having to login twice for them both to complete. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Theo, could you perhaps provide me with an example code that I can try? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `APPDATA` from `Destination` and it should work. Use following code:

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\Server\Share\*.lnk" -Destination "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've amended that but unfortunately nothing happens, it appears to run but no file appears in that folder. I think it might be something to do with copying from a UNC path as I've tried to copy to the local desktop and it keeps returning an error that it cannot find the file path. Any more suggestions would be brilliant. Thanks

Comment: @Admaine You may use `Test-Path` to see if path is accessible.

Comment: Hi, that returns false yet the drive is mapped and fully accessible?

Comment: You need to check with which account you are running the script and see if that account has access to the share.

Comment: OK, I see your point there and realised I was running Powershell as administrator. The `Test-Path` now returns true however, the command I ran to copy the file now returns `Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Devices and Printers.lnk' is
denied.` My initial thought was that I haven't set the execution policy but I don't have access to do that logged on as myself. Could I setup that in a ps1? Would that work?

Comment: Hi guys, I have resolved the above issue however, it's lead me on to a follow on issue. I apply this script when a user logs in to Windows 10 but I then want to run a separate task (that is a part of the same ps1 file) which removes a whole host of Bloatware from the OS. I've tried to add a `;` and additionally `and` but they both still require the user to login twice to complete both tasks. My full script at the moment is followed in my comment below: Any help would be amazing.

Comment: `Copy-Item -Path "\\Server\Share\*.lnk" -Destination "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"; $AppList = @(
    "*Microsoft.3dbuilder*"
    "*AdobeSystemsIncorporated.AdobePhotoshopExpress*"
    "*Microsoft.WindowsAlarms*"
    "*Microsoft.Asphalt8Airborne*"
    "*microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps*"
    "*Microsoft.WindowsCamera*"
    "*king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga*"
    "*Microsoft.DrawboardPDF*"
)

foreach ($App in $AppList) {
    Get-AppxPackage -Name $App | Remove-AppxPackage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} `

Comment: @Admaine Please do not enter all that code in a comment, but [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54706625/edit) your question and put it in there (nicely formatted of course..)

Comment: @Theo OK I think I've done it, are you able to assist?