# PowerShell through Group Policy

Tags: powershell, windows-10, gpo

I have two separate PowerShell (.ps1) files that I'd like to run one after the other when a user logs on to a PC. They're fairly straightforward tasks. The first copies a shortcut from a network location to all users AppData folder.

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\Server\Share\*.lnk" -Destination "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
```

The second .ps1 file removes a load of bloatware from Windows 10, I won't put all the code in here as it's quite repetitive but it basically lists a load of apps and finally removes them.

```
$AppList = @(
    "*Microsoft.3dbuilder*"
    "*AdobeSystemsIncorporated.AdobePhotoshopExpress*"
    "*Microsoft.WindowsAlarms*"
    "*Microsoft.Asphalt8Airborne*"
)
foreach ($App in $AppList) {
    Get-AppxPackage -Name $App | Remove-AppxPackage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

If I place the two files into the same logon policy, the first script will run but the second one doesn't until the user logs off and back on again (I'd like them both to run at the same time).

I've tried placing them both in the same file and separating then with a `;`, this didn't work so tried `and`, again no joy. I've also tried creating a master file (with the two .ps1 files in the same location) and running the following, again this didn't work.

```
&"$PSScriptroot\Copy Devices and Printers Shortcut.ps1"    &"$PSScriptroot\BloatwareRemoval.ps1"
```

I've also tried separating the above with `;` and `and` with no joy.

**Edit** I've resolved this with the following pd1 file: 
`Get-ChildItem \\File\Location | ForEach-Object {
  & $_.FullName
}`

Comment: Why not a single script to get both the operations done?

Comment: Hi, Are you able to help me out? I did try that but couldn't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: okay.. Let me help you to take them in a single script. the way you are calling is no more a question then.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the File Explorer as commented in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706625/powershell-command-to-copy-from-network-location-to-all-users-profile)?

Comment: @Admaine: see the below answer, if it fits the need then I will remove my comment here.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, this script you should save as a `.ps1` file and call it however you want. It will do both the operations together. I have added error handling but ideally you should parse them in a file so that you can refer in case of any failure.

```
If( (Test-Path -Path "\\Server\Share\*.lnk") -and (Test-Path -Path "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"))
{
Copy-Item -Path "\\Server\Share\*.lnk" -Destination "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
}
else
{
"Invalid path. Kindly validate. "
}

@("*Microsoft.3dbuilder*","*AdobeSystemsIncorporated.AdobePhotoshopExpress*","*Microsoft.WindowsAlarms*","*Microsoft.Asphalt8Airborne*")|% {
    try{
    Get-AppxPackage -Name $_ | Remove-AppxPackage -ErrorAction stop
    }
    catch
    {
    $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Ranadit Dutta, thanks for this. I seem to still be stuck in the same position. Let me provide a bit more background which might help explain it.  I've initially exported the startlayout into an xml file, this has been added to the "Start Screen Layout" GPP. Devices and Printers however doesn't copy (I believe this is because its an embedded function within Control Panel) therefore, I created a shortcut to devices and printers and added it to a network location that all users have access to. Please see next comment.....

Comment: Once a user logs in it then runs the first part of the script which copies this shortcut to the AppData folder for all users, the startlayout xml then references this location and adds it to the start menu. This works successfully but like I say it will run this script but not the second which removes the bloatware. I keep being in the position where the copy works and the startlayout works, then the bloatware removal stops. Hope you can help further?

Comment: We need to isolate the issues. Run the script normally and see if you are able to remove the bloatware. Also run the script in task scheduler and see. It is more of a permission issue I think.

Comment: Yes, the script runs to do both tasks however, it just doesn't do them at the same time when logging on. It will only run the removal part after I login a second time. The order I need this to run is: 1) Copy shortcut to all users AppData Folder 2) Run the startlayout xml that locates this shortcut and adds it to the start menu (this is from the "Start Screen Layout GP" under User Config > Admin Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar 3) Run the bloatware removal script. Currently it's only running numbers 1 and 2. It's as though the startmenu part cancels action 3. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this with the following pd1 file: 
`Get-ChildItem \\File\Location | ForEach-Object {
  & $_.FullName
}`